# My snippets works with a single press of the tab key on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

My snippets work with a single press of the tab key *like=>*(**prop Tab**) on Visual Studio 2022.
I want it to works when the tab key is pressed twice *like=>*(**prop Tab+Tab**).
How can I change this?

I couldn't find any information on the subject when I searched the internet.